# Dfa for a language {0,1} that has even length or it ends with a 0.

Tags: automata

Accepted strings would be {"", 11, 100, 1010, 1111} And it would reject everything that is not even length or it ends with a 0.

I constructed two dfa, one that accepts all possible even combinations, and one that ends with a 0, but I can't combine them.

After a bit of thinking, I kinda believe that three states must be enough, but still can't make it work.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I originally misread the question, this should be the corrected answer:

State 1 is initial, states 1 and 2 are terminal (i.e. accepting).

[image]

There are three relevantly distinct possibilites at each step:

1. The current number of characters is even; accepting.
2. The current number of characters is odd, but the last character was zero; accepting.
3. The current number of characters is odd and the last character was a one; rejecting.

Comment: 2. Must be rejected, and 3. must be accepted according to the requirements.

Comment: You are right, I misread. I just corrected the answer.

Comment: This DFA will accept 001 on state 2, so that breaks the even rule, I am thinking I need more states.

Comment: Are you sure? It seems to me that 001 would leave the machine on state 3:
1  --0->  2  --0->  1  --1->  3.

Comment: Yes, you are correct